# IBook G4 Charging Problems?

Tags: mac, battery, charging

I am having some trouble with my iBook G4. It seems that whenever I plug it into the wall charger that it doesn't charge. It's not the charger's fault. There's a button on the back of it right next the battery, when I push it all five lights next to the button light up. I don't think where the charger is put in is broken. Any help? .

Answer (score 1):

Is the light not coming on or is it not charging?

If it's not charging it's probably the internal board, which is about a $300 replacement. Been through one of those myself before I switched to the new (and *much improved*) magnetic adapters. Of course, the only way to switch is to purchase a new one.